# DWS CreateFolder() files are getting created on shareppoint "Style Library"

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2007

I am Creating folder on Sharepoint as:

```
Dws ds = new Dws();
ds.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(Login,Password);
ds.Url = "http://myservername/_vti_bin/DWS.asmx";
ds.PreAuthenticate = true;
string strResult = "";
strResult = ds.CreateFolder("SiteName/Documents/NewFolderName");
```

I am getting `strResult` value as `"RESULT"` .

Here Folders are getting created but not in above specified path.
It is getting created in "Style Library" of Sharepoint.

But why?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
strResult = ds.CreateFolder("Documents/NewFolderName");
```

I have a site called "DWS" on my root site collection (note the difference in ds.Url between your code and mine):

```
Dws ds = new Dws();
ds.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(Login,Password);
ds.Url = "http://myservername/DWS/_vti_bin/DWS.asmx";
ds.PreAuthenticate = true;
string strResult = "";
strResult = ds.CreateFolder("Documents/NewFolderName");
```