# How to create folder in Sharepoint on specified url using web services?

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2007

Currently i am using DWS CreateFolder function to create folder on Sharepoint (using C#).
But problem i am facing is that:

As per CreateFolder Defination:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms774480.aspx

(Def: Creates a subfolder in the document library of the current Document Workspace site)

It is creating folder in current workspace i.e not on url path i am giving.(in my case it is creating folder in Style Library)

My Previous post:

[DWS CreateFolder() files are getting created on shareppoint "Style Library"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2130743/dws-createfolder-files-are-getting-created-on-shareppoint-style-library)

Is there any other way to createfolder?

Regards,
Jene

Comment: see my response to your previous post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use "MKCOL" method of  "HttpWebRequest" .